# Disable @CreationTimestamp in testing class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So I'm using Hibernate's annotations `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp`. It works fine, but I have this case when unit testing where I need to create objects in specific dates.

I think it is not possible to deactivate this annotations so the first thing I thought was remove them and do something like this:

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    if (createdDate == null) {
        createdDate = new Date();
    }
}
```

I don't like it this way because I'll have to do a refactor of my entities just for one test case.

The other solution I think it can be better is to create an sql file with the data I need and execute it with Spring before when running my tests.

What do you think is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem in tests, the best solution that I came up with is:
Mock static method in Clock.systemUTC so it will return Clock.fixed()

```java
try (MockedStatic<Clock> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(Clock.class)) {
                utilities.when(Clock::systemUTC)
                        .thenReturn(Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2018-08-22T10:00:00Z"), ZoneOffset.UTC));
                System.out.println(Instant.now()) //here perform actions in past
            }
    System.out.println(Instant.now()) // here perform in current time
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change your production code just for a test case. Just modify the creation date attribute on your test objects?

Comment: The thing is I cannot do that because Hibernate overrides the value I setted when I persist it.

Comment: You could persist it. Then re-load it and change the creation date then.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the data type of the attribute equipped with `@UpdateTimestamp` was a `LocalDateTime`. I have solved it this way:

```
ShiftLog shiftLog1 = ShiftLog.builder().build();
ShiftLog shiftLog2 = ShiftLog.builder().build();
ShiftLog shiftLog3 = ShiftLog.builder().build();
LocalDateTime thePast = LocalDateTime.of(1979, 4, 3, 6, 45, 31);
try (MockedStatic<LocalDateTime> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(LocalDateTime.class)) {
   utilities.when(() -> LocalDateTime.now(ArgumentMatchers.any(Clock.class))).thenReturn(thePast);
   repository.save(shiftLog1);
   repository.save(shiftLog2);
}
// Now the @UpdateTimestamp is untouched again.
repository.save(shiftLog3);
```